Information about getent group information
I am trying to understand where the numeric group information is stored on my Linux system:
getent group 6574322
LinuxShareTest:*:6574322:peter.muller

But grep 6574322 /etc/group gives no entry
I suspect getent to access a network directory service, how can I find this service on my Linux machine ?

Does the group entry of your /etc/nsswitch.conf file mention ldap or sss?

Yes, we need the information in /etc/nsswitch.conf to help you
